# Set selected using jQuery

Tags: jquery, html-select, selector, attr

I'm trying to change the selected option within this list.. Its only working for some and not others?

selectedVal will either be Kelly Green, Navy etc...

```
 var selectedVal = $(this).text();

 $("#product-variants-option-0 option[text=" + selectedVal+"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

This is the select list:

```
<select class="single-option-selector" id="product-variants-option-0">
<option value="Gunmetal Heather">Gunmetal Heather</option>
<option value="Kelly Green">Kelly Green</option>
<option value="Navy">Navy</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use value attribute instead of text in your selector. i.e:

```
$("#product-variants-option-0 option[value=" + selectedVal+"]").attr("selected","selected") ;
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that... Thanks very much! perfect!

Answer (score 4):

There's a much simpler way to set the selected option of a `<select>` element.

Just call [jQuery's `.val()` method](http://api.jquery.com/val/) against the `<select>` itself:

```
$("#product-variants-option-0").val( selectedVal );
```