# jQuery - Select option by option text

Tags: jquery

So, here is a select I have:

```
<select id="sel1">
            <option selected="selected" value=""></option>
            <option value="AFG">AFGANISTAN</option>
            <option value="ALB">ALBANIA</option>
            <option value="DZA">ALGERIA</option>
</select>
```

How to dynamically select an option not by value (AFG), but by option text (AFGANISTAN)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set selected using jQuery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4572567/set-selected-using-jquery)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$("option:contains('ALGERIA')").prop('selected', true);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `.filter()`:

```
$('#sel1 option').filter(function () { 
   return $(this).text() == "AFGANISTAN"; 
}).attr('selected','selected'); // <- SET OPTION SELECTED
```

**[Working Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/sqtpm1cb/)**

Comment: `.prop( 'selected', true )` can also be used instead of `.attr( 'selected','selected' )`

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#sel1 option').each(function () { 
   if( $(this).text() == "AFGANISTAN")
       $(this).attr('selected','selected');
})
```